# `Error creating target Swift AST context: (null)` in REPL

Tags: xcode, swift, command-line-interface, read-eval-print-loop

I've seen several (well, not that many, but a few) questions here on SO dealing with this error, but none of the proposed solutions worked for me. This is what I get

```
$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.1.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.15 clang-700.1.81). Type :help for assistance.
warning: Swift error in module repl_swift: 
    Error creating module Swift AST context: couldn't get a ClangImporter
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module dyld: 
    Error creating module Swift AST context: couldn't get a ClangImporter
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreFoundation: 
    Error creating module Swift AST context: couldn't get a ClangImporter
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

...

warning: Swift error in module ServiceManagement: 
    Error creating module Swift AST context: couldn't get a ClangImporter
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libxslt.1.dylib: 
    Error creating module Swift AST context: couldn't get a ClangImporter
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

error: Error creating target Swift AST context: (null)
```

This may or may not have happened after I issued some command that I don't remember (and my bash history does not help very much). The odd thing is that if I uninstall Xcode, the REPL starts working correctly. If I re-install Xcode, however, the errors come back. I'm on Xcode 7.2.1 (7C1002), by the way. Thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To see your current Xcode path:

`xcode-select -p`

Mine was an old path:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Then update this path via:

`sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Comment: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'

Comment: @aguilarpgc I am also facing the error `error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'`