# Cannot run Swift REPL without it barfing a bunch of dylib warnings

Tags: swift, xcode8, read-eval-print-loop

I just installed Xcode 8.2 and attempted to run the Swift REPL. I'm running into the following warnings. How do I resolve? Note that this is on a brand new MBP with Sierra. Xcode is one of a very few applications that are currently installed aside from the standard set.

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1). Type :help for assistance.
warning: Swift error in module repl_swift.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module dyld.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libz.1.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libedit.3.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libpanel.5.4.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libncurses.5.4.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Foundation.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libSystem.B.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libicucore.A.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libauto.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module DiskArbitration.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libarchive.2.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libxml2.2.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CFNetwork.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module SystemConfiguration.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreServices.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module liblangid.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module IOKit.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libCRFSuite.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libc++abi.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libc++.1.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcache.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcommonCrypto.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcompiler_rt.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcopyfile.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcorecrypto.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libdispatch.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libdyld.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libkeymgr.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module liblaunch.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libmacho.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libquarantine.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libremovefile.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_asl.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_blocks.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_c.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_configuration.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_coreservices.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_coretls.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_dnssd.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_info.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_kernel.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_m.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_malloc.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_network.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_networkextension.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_notify.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_platform.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_pthread.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_sandbox.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_secinit.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_symptoms.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_trace.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libunwind.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libxpc.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Security.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libbz2.1.0.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module liblzma.5.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libbsm.0.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libnetwork.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module FSEvents.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CarbonCore.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Metadata.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module OSServices.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module SearchKit.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module AE.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module LaunchServices.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module DictionaryServices.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module SharedFileList.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libenergytrace.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libkxld.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcoretls.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libxar.1.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libpam.2.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libpcap.A.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module NetFS.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module TCC.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libmecabra.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CFOpenDirectory.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module ServiceManagement.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libmarisa.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module LanguageModeling.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libxslt.1.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module NetAuth.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module ApplicationServices.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libChineseTokenizer.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcmph.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libiconv.2.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreEmoji.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module loginsupport.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreText.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module ATS.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module ColorSync.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module HIServices.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module LangAnalysis.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module PrintCore.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module QD.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module SpeechSynthesis.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libFontParser.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libFontRegistry.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module AppleJPEG.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module IOSurface.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module MultitouchSupport.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcups.2.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreAudio.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module AudioToolbox.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Kerberos.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module GSS.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libresolv.9.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libQuadrature.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Heimdal.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module OpenDirectory.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libheimdal-asn1.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CommonAuth.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module SecurityFoundation.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreFoundation.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libobjc.A.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libswiftCore.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libswiftDarwin.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsqlite3.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreGraphics.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module ImageIO.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Accelerate.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module vImage.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module vecLib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libvDSP.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libBNNS.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libvMisc.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libLAPACK.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libBLAS.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libLinearAlgebra.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libSparseBLAS.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libJPEG.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libTIFF.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libPng.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libGIF.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libJP2.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libRadiance.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcompression.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreData.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.
```

Comment: This may help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438851/error-creating-target-swift-ast-context-null-in-repl

Comment: Thanks @Satachito. I already tried that before I posted my question. No go.

Answer (score 17):

Go to **Xcode** - **Preferences**.

Check if **Command Line Tools** is set.

[image]

Comment: It's possible to see this error when you install command lines tools before installing Xcode. For some reason like "installing a terminal application which has a dependency for command line tools" After that if you install Xcode it's possible to take this error, and congrats for lamahk for answering it. Must be valid answer for my opinion

Comment: I used to get the same errors as the OP. This solution fixed it for me.