# I was on Terminal and I typed swift and errors appear

Tags: swift, terminal

I opened up Terminal on my MacBook, and I typed in Swift and errors appear, and I don't know what to do. If anyone can help me with this situation, it will be appreciated. Below this paragraph will be the errors.

```
Groshvins-MBP:~ P.W$ swift
warning: Swift error in module repl_swift.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module dyld.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libz.1.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcompression.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libSystem.B.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcache.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcommonCrypto.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcompiler_rt.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcopyfile.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcorecrypto.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libdispatch.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libdyld.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libkeymgr.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module liblaunch.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libmacho.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libquarantine.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libremovefile.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_asl.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_blocks.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_c.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_configuration.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_coreservices.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_darwin.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_dnssd.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_info.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_m.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_malloc.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_network.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_networkextension.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_notify.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_sandbox.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_secinit.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_kernel.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_platform.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_pthread.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_symptoms.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsystem_trace.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libunwind.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libxpc.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libclosured.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libobjc.A.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libc++abi.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libc++.1.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module liblzma.5.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libswiftCore.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Foundation.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreFoundation.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libicucore.A.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libauto.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module DiskArbitration.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libarchive.2.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libxml2.2.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CFNetwork.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module SystemConfiguration.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreServices.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module liblangid.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module IOKit.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libCRFSuite.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Security.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libenergytrace.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libbsm.0.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libkxld.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcoretls.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libpam.2.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libsqlite3.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libxar.1.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libbz2.1.0.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libnetwork.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libapple_nghttp2.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libpcap.A.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libboringssl.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libusrtcp.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libapple_crypto.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module FSEvents.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CarbonCore.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Metadata.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module OSServices.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module SearchKit.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module AE.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module LaunchServices.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module DictionaryServices.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module SharedFileList.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module NetFS.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module NetAuth.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module loginsupport.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module TCC.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libmecabra.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module ApplicationServices.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreGraphics.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreText.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module ImageIO.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module ColorSync.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module ATS.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module ColorSyncLegacy.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module HIServices.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module LangAnalysis.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module PrintCore.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module QD.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module SpeechSynthesis.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module SkyLight.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Accelerate.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreDisplay.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module IOSurface.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Metal.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module MultitouchSupport.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module QuartzCore.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module vImage.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module vecLib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libvDSP.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libBNNS.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libQuadrature.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libvMisc.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libLAPACK.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libBLAS.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libLinearAlgebra.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libSparse.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libSparseBLAS.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module IOAccelerator.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module IOPresentment.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module DSExternalDisplay.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libCoreFSCache.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreImage.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreVideo.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module OpenGL.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module GraphVisualizer.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module MetalPerformanceShaders.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libFosl_dynamic.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module FaceCore.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module OpenCL.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libFontParser.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libFontRegistry.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libJPEG.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libTIFF.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libPng.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libGIF.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libJP2.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libRadiance.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module AppleJPEG.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module MetalTools.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module MPSCore.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module MPSImage.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module MPSMatrix.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module MPSNeuralNetwork.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libGLU.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libGFXShared.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libGL.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libGLImage.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libCoreVMClient.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcups.2.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Kerberos.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module GSS.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libresolv.9.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libiconv.2.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Heimdal.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libheimdal-asn1.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module OpenDirectory.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CommonAuth.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CFOpenDirectory.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module SecurityFoundation.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module APFS.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libutil.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreAudio.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module AudioToolbox.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module AppleSauce.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module LinguisticData.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libmarisa.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module Lexicon.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libChineseTokenizer.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libcmph.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module LanguageModeling.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreData.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module CoreEmoji.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module ServiceManagement.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module BackgroundTaskManagement.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module libxslt.1.dylib.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

Welcome to Apple Swift version 4.0.3 (swiftlang-900.0.74.1 clang-900.0.39.2). Type :help for assistance.
  1>
```

Comment: Perhaps this https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3392 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204362/cannot-run-swift-repl-without-it-barfing-a-bunch-of-dylib-warnings?

Comment: Martin R Unfortunately it didn't work, but now it shows this message:       Last login: Wed Jan 31 17:49:47 on ttys001
Groshvins-MBP:~ P.W$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
Groshvins-MBP:~ P.W$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 4.0.3 (swiftlang-900.0.74.1 clang-900.0.39.2). Type :help for assistance.
  1>